# Fix invalid JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, validation

I have a huge file that unfortunately contains invalid JSON.
It looks like list of arrays, **not separated** with a comma:

```
[{
    "key": "value"
}]
[
    [{
            "key": "value",
            "obj": {}
        },
        {}
    ]
]
[{
    "key": "value",
    "obj": {}
}]
```

The content inside every square brackets pair seems to be a **valid JSON by itself**.

The question is how to **fix this JSON quickly with "search and replace"**? (or any other method)

Tried many combinations including replacing "**][**" to "**],[**" and wrapping the whole file with one more square brackets pair making it array of arrays.
Every time it gives me invalid JSON.

Please help.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com this might help you. This is an online json validator.

Comment: Show the result of your search and replace on this sample data

Comment: If you replace all "][" to "],[" you also need to add a `[` at the beginning of the file and `]` at the end so it is one big array.

Comment: @Venify, this is exactly what I did.
This is what jsonlint says: Error: Parse error on line 12260956:
...,     {}    ]   ]
--------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got 'EOF'

Comment: The error means that there is a surplus `[` that is not closed.

Comment: @Venify, I understand but now how can I find the matching tag in such a huge file. There should be a simpler method...

Comment: @Dez That duplicate link is inadequate because this question is tagged with php and not tagged with javascript.  The dupe is a javascript solution.  We do not know the source of this data or if it can be corrected by a client-side language for the project's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the closing brackets with '],' and wrap the entire string in brackets.

This snippet illustrates the method with the supplied sample data by applying the algorithm and then calling eval on the resulting string.

```js
let jsonString = `[{
    "key": "value"
}]
[
    [{
            "key": "value",
            "obj": {}
        },
        {}
    ]
]
[{
    "key": "value",
    "obj": {}
}]`;

jsonString = jsonString.replace( /]/g, '],' );
jsonString = '[' + jsonString + ']';

myObject = eval( jsonString );

console.log( typeof myObject);
console.log( myObject.length );
console.log( myObject );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic php solution, but I would cringe to have to use this as a reliable source of data.  This is a bandaid.  Whatever code is producing this invalid json NEEDS to be fixed asap.

My regex pattern will seek all occurrences of `]`, zero or more spaces, then `]` then it will add a comma after the `]`.

The entire string is wrapped in square brackets to make the json string valid.

The risk may or may not be obvious to all -- if any of the actual keys or values contain strings that qualify for replacement, then they will be damaged.  This is why using regex on json is not recommended.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3tTSY))

```
$bad_json = '[{
    "key": "value"
}]
[
    [{
            "key": "value",
            "obj": {}
        },
        {}
    ]
]
[{
    "key": "value",
    "obj": {}
}]';
$valid_json = "[" . preg_replace("~]\K(?=\s*\[)~", ",", $bad_json) . "]";

var_export(json_decode($valid_json, true));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'value',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'key' => 'value',
        'obj' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'value',
      'obj' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```